# International Shipping Notice on Checkout using jQuery Array

Tags: woocommerce

My code works with one exception; I do not know how to turn the country code into an array. I've tried `{1, 2, 3};` and `[1, 2, 3];` and `["1", "2"];` and other formats without success.

I need the country code to be an array.

Thanks to Milney, this is the working version:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'international_shipping_notice' );
function international_shipping_notice() {
    echo '<div class="international-shipping-notice woocommerce-info" style="display:none">Please allow 5-10 business days for delivery after order processing.</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'show_international_shipping_notice' );
function show_international_shipping_notice(){ ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var countryCode = ["DK", "SE"];

        $('select#billing_country').change(function(){
            selectedCountries = $(this).val();

        if (countryCode.some(r => selectedCountries.includes(r))){
        $('.international-shipping-notice').show();
        } else {

        $('.international-shipping-notice').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Okay, how do you define an array in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will define an array:

```
var countryCodes = ["UK"];
```

But this doesn't seem to make sense in the rest of your code... Do you really mean you get an array and want to check if country code is in it?

```
if ( selectedCountry.indexOf(countryCode) != -1)
```

---

If you want to check if **any** of the values are in the array if would be more like:

if(selectedCountry.some(r=> countryCode.includes(r))){

Assuming you have a select element like

```
<select id="billing_country" multiple>
```

Then this code will work:

```
var countryCodes = ['UK'];
$('select#billing_country').change(function(){
    selectedCountries = $(this).val();
    if (countryCodes.some(r => selectedCountries.includes(r))){
```

Comment: Not sure, that's what I'm asking. I tried making an array using different examples, and according to you I need to add that extra if?

Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I tried this without success: `<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var countryCode = ["UK", "SE", "DK", "FI"];

            $('select#billing_country').change(function(){
            selectedCountry = $('select#billing_country').val();
        
        if ( selectedCountry.indexOf(countryCode) != -1){
            $('.international-shipping-notice').show();
        } else {

        $('.international-shipping-notice').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>`

Comment: You can't do both see my latest edit. That first if statement I posted was if you were looking for a single value.

Comment: OK. That did not work either. Using that makes it unable to select at all. I need it to be an array of country codes and if one of those are chosen, display the message. If not, hide the message.

Comment: @JamesAndrew - What do you mean "unable to select at all"? That code does work - check https://jsfiddle.net/pmu7hs3b/ for an example

Comment: Yes, that version works, but not with WooCommerce on checkout, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Oh perhaps you dont have the some/includes methods - just change that to a double loop, i.e. foreach(element in selectedCountries){ foreach(element in countryCodes){ if (element1 == element2)